# how to create this type of art illustrator

Tags: shadow, adobe-illustrator, stock

I wanted to know is there is any one who had this design or any one could tell me the way how to create this type of shadow behind the words in the following image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hYrg.jpg)

so is there is anyway to create this in illustrator

Comment: Do you want to create it programmatically? If not, why is this question on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge that design would probably be a vector, which someone may or may not have. Overall you could remake a similar on with Photoshop, or illustrator, or a free editing software and overlaying white letters on a background with a drop shadow. There are tons of tutorials on google of how to achieve these task hopefully this helps